# Weird black spots when taking pictures with the camera

Tags: camera, hardware

I recently noticed there are black spots on the camera preview screen as well as the final picture saved by the camera. When I zoom in the spopts are not static, that is, it is possible to zoom to the centre of the screen while in camera preview mode, and the spots will move eventually move out of view.

This is a picture taken using this camera:
[image]

This is what it looks like when this picture is zoomed in (zooming in on the top spot above; each spot looks different):
[image]

The spot also appears on the camera preview screen:
[image]

However, in the camera preview screen this spot is not at a fixed place and moves when zoomed out. Here is an example of what happens to the top spot when zooming in at the centre of the screen:

[image]

These spots are also seen when using a different camera app (Open Camera). The screenshots above were from the default camera app. The phone is Samsung Galaxy S7 (SM-G930K) with Android 8.0. The screen looks normal otherwise. This problem is not seen on the front camera.

What is going on here? Is this a problem with the camera hardware? Is this just a loose wire or something, or is this fixable?

Comment: Considering that the spots are fixed in position but follow the zooming, it may be a cracked lens or small particles blocking the lens? You might want to open the back cover and check the lens if you're feeling adventurous (you can refer to the guides on [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Samsung_Galaxy_S7)).

Comment: @AndrewT. By just looking at the lens (without removing cover) I don't see any cracks, but I don't know enough about it to say for sure either. Is it possible for such cracks to be invisible to the naked eye? I am guessing that a dusty lens is a lot less serious than a cracked lens

Comment: Come to think of it, yeah, I think cracks won't look like that. Possibly a dirty lens.

Comment: @AndrewT. The biggest spot recently moved out of view, so the dirt theory seems to be correct. There are still two smaller spots on the screen, but I am hoping they are just much smaller dust specks stuck to the lens which cannot be moved by simple shaking, and not anything more serious. I guess now it's just a matter of getting motivated enough to open the thing up.